# Get streaming URL of UPnP-device with Cling in Java

Tags: java, upnp, android-cling

I wanted to use Cling for my Java application to browse the directory of my Panasonic dmr-bct720 BluRay recorder. I tried the first example but Cling couldn't find the device. With VLC I can browse it and watch the videos.

Can anyone give me an example how to display the streaming URLs?